# Data Validation

Tags: list, validation

I have a list in SharePoint. It collects the date it was entered and then a Dynamic Column called Days in House.

This column should update by subtracting the creation date from today's date and update the column to represent days. Is this possible to do in Sharepoint, and if so can anyone offer an article giving some information relating to the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of SharePoint default feature calculated column to achieve this. Please refer the below link.

[Calculated Column in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thank you Suren. I believe I have the calculated column working now.